Minimum MSE Estimator among all possible estimates. Sheldon Ross Exercise 59 in Chapter 7
In Sheldon Ross' Introduction to Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists, the problem $59$ in chapter $7$ asks us that if $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ denote a sample from a population whose mean value is $\theta$, then among all unbiased estimators of $\theta$ of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}X_{i}$ where $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}=1$, the one with the minimum mean square error is when $\lambda_{i}=1/n$ for each $i=1,...,n$.
Further Context
The question asks us to use results from Example 7.7b inorder to solve this. Exercise 7.7b states that if $d_{i},i=1,...,n$ denotes unbiased estimators of some parameter such that $Var(d_{i})=\sigma_{i}^{2}$ , then the unbiased estimator $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}d_{i}=1$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}=1$ is given by the solution,
$$\lambda_{i}=\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sigma_{i}^{2}}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sigma_{j}^{2}}}$$
My Attempt:
I don't think that the result from Exercise 7.7b can be used here as we are to minimize over an uncountably many $d_{j}$ corresponding to a vector $(\overline{\lambda}_{j})=(\lambda_{1,j},...,\lambda_{n,j})$  such that $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\lambda_{j,n}=1$.
I want to solve it this way.
We have that for any $\overline{\lambda}=(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}=1$,
$$Var(d_{\overline{\lambda}})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{2}\sigma^{2}$$.
So, it seems to me that we should minimize $a=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{2}\sigma^{2}$ subject to the condition that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}=1$.
This will occur when the sphere $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}^{2}=\frac{a}{\sigma^{2}}$ for a value of $a$ becomes tangent to the plane $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{k}=1$.
Now it is clear (to me) that this happens when $\lambda_{i}=\frac{1}{n}$.
That is, the coordinates $(\lambda_{i},...,\lambda_{n})$ of the point where the sphere and plane are tangent will be given by the point of intersection of the line passing through the origin with direction ratios $(1,1,...,1)$ and the plane $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_{k}=1$ and this has the unique solution $\lambda_{i}=\frac{1}{n}$.
Question: Is what I have done above correct? If yes then I am right in saying that I don't need the result from Exercise 7.7b inorder to conclude that $\lambda_{i}=\frac{1}{n}$?
